# How to include manager data with employee data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called `Employees`

| ID | Full Name | Employee Type | Employment Rate | Manager ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 143 | Sam Smith | Full Time | Wage | 146 |
| 144 | Jay Reddy | Part Time | Wage | 146 |
| 145 | Nick Young | Full Time | Wage | 146 |
| 146 | Trevor Simm | Full Time | Salary | 147 |
| 147 | Justin Peters | Part Time | Salary | 147 |
| 148 | Lisa Howard | Full Time | Salary | 140 |
| 149 | Nicky West | Full Time | Salary | 140 |
| 150 | Gemma Yu | Full Time | Wage | 146 |
| 151 | Sally Zhang | Part Time | Salary | 140 |
| 152 | James Hillary | Full Time | Wage | 146 |
| 153 | Nikita Shaw | Full Time | Wage | 146 |

I want to run a query where it should return Wage employees. I want to also include those Wage employees' managers in the query so it should return something like this:

| ID | Full Name | Employee Type | Employment Rate | Manager ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 143 | Sam Smith | Full Time | Wage | 146 |
| 144 | Jay Reddy | Part Time | Wage | 146 |
| 145 | Nick Young | Full Time | Wage | 146 |
| 146 | Trevor Simm | Full Time | Salary | 147 |
| 147 | Justin Peters | Part Time | Salary | 147 |
| 150 | Gemma Yu | Full Time | Wage | 146 |
| 152 | James Hillary | Full Time | Wage | 146 |
| 153 | Nikita Shaw | Full Time | Wage | 146 |

Querying the Wage employees is easy enough though wondering if you can help me with the query so that it also includes their managers in the list:

```sql
Select * From Employees
Where [Employment Rate] = 'Wage'
```

Comment: I can't say I follow the logic here, you need to explain further.

Comment: What is the logic that includes 147?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a sub query like like this

```
Select * 
From Employees
Where [Employment Rate] = 'Wage'
   or ID in (SELECT [Manager ID] FROM Employees Where [Employment Rate] = 'Wage')
```

You could also use a UNION statement -- which I like better because I would add a new column in there showing the source of the data -- in my experience you always want this when working with data in this way:

```
SELECT 'Worker' as SOURCE,
       ID, [Full Name], [Employee Type], [Employment Rate], [Manager ID]
FROM Employees
WHERE [Employment Rate] = 'Wage'

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Manager' as SOURCE,
       ID, [Full Name], [Employee Type], [Employment Rate], [Manager ID]
FROM Employees
WHERE ID IN (SELECT [Manager ID] FROM Employees Where [Employment Rate] = 'Wage')
```

Note -- if a employee has a wage rate they will appear twice with this query, but not with the first one.

Comment: "if a employee has a wage rate" do you mean if a manager has a wage rate?

Comment: @DaleK -- well a manager is an employee -- so yes?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a CTE to determine the relevant employees you can then union on a query to obtain their managers e.g.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM Employees
    WHERE [Employment Rate] = 'Wage'
)
SELECT * FROM cte
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE Id IN (SELECT [Manager ID] FROM cte);
```